# Custom Paging in ASP using Offset and Fetch

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012

I am developing an custom pager but stuck that how to use the functionality of Offset and Fetch in ASP.NET`SELECT columns from table order by ID
                         OFFSET 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only`
Just want a head start how i use this in my Repeater Control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the question, but it seems like all you need to do is something like this

SELECT columns from table order by ID
OFFSET (Page-1)*PageSize rows fetch next PageSize rows only

Where Page is a page number and PageSize - amount of items on 1 page.

Comment: Yes exactly but how to do it using asp.net repeater control I m newbie in procedures.kindly help me out.